# Does `__declspec(novtable)` no use?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, virtual

As we know, `novtable` means that do not create a virtual table for a pure abstract class. But when I run the code blow, something wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};

struct __declspec(novtable) B{
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};

struct C{
    void fun(){}
};

struct _declspec(novtable) D : public A {};

int main(){
    cout<<sizeof(int*)<<endl;  //4
    cout<<sizeof(A)<<endl;  //4
    cout<<sizeof(B)<<endl;  //4
    cout<<sizeof(C)<<endl;  //1
    cout<<sizeof(D)<<endl;  //4
    return 0;
}
```

the size of `A` and `B` are same, does that means `novtable` no use?

ps: compiled with vs2019

Comment: It suppresses the list of pointers to virtual functions.  Still used in an abstract class without novtable, it triggers the "pure virtual function call" runtime error.  But does still reserve the space to store the vtable pointer in the object.  It will be used by the derived concrete class.  It is a micro-optimization, there is very little point to it on modern machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no vtable for the class `B`. This does not mean there is no vtable *pointer* in objects of instances of `B`. The vtable pointer is needed so that

For example, if you create an instance of BDerived:

```
struct BDerived : public B {
    void fun() {}
};

BDerived bd;
B* pb = &bd;
pb->fun();
```

`pb` points to a `B` sub-object, which contains a vtable pointer, which points to `BDerived`'s vtable. When you call `pb->fun()`, the program will look at `pb`'s vtable pointer, follow it to `BDerived`'s vtable, and then look in that vtable to find `BDerived`'s implementation of `fun`.

---

In other words, the compiler translates the code to something like this:

```
vtable A_vtable = {NULL};
struct A {
    vtable *vtable_ptr;
};

// No vtable, but still a vtable pointer
struct B {
    vtable *vtable_ptr;
};

void BDerived_fun() {};
vtable BDerived_vtable = {&BDerived_fun};
struct BDerived : public B {
};

BDerived bd; bd.vtable_ptr = &BDerived_vtable;
B* pb = &bd;
(pb->vtable_ptr.fun)(pb);
```

Answer (score 3):

[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/novtable?view=vs-2019) reads:

> The `__declspec(novtable)` stops the compiler from generating code to initialize the `vfptr` in the constructor(s) and destructor of the class.  In many cases, this removes the only references to the `vtable` that are associated with the class and, thus, the linker will remove it.

In other words, `vfptr` will still be present as the data member, but its value will not be initialized. For example, if you manage to call a pure virtual function, instead of a message like "A pure virtual function call", you'll get a segmentation fault.

> The size of `A` and `B` are same, does that means `novtable` no use?

The purpose of `__declspec(novtable)` is not to reduce the object size, but to remove some initialization code that you don't need and `vtable`s that you don't need either.